# How we can specify figure page in LaTeX?

Tags: floats

How we can specify figure page? For example I want show a figure on top of page 5.

Comment: I think it is pretty impossible to do it without imposing a lot restrictions on the text flow. For example `\begin{document}...\newpage...\newpage...\newpage...\newpage..` ...then @Ambika's code... `...\end{document}`.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't know when in the text the desired page will appear, you can use a combination of packages to do what you want:

- The `everypage` package adds a hook that you can run at each page
- The `afterpage` package lets you insert code into the next page

You can combine those like I did below, so that at every page, the page number is checked, and if its the page that comes before the one you want, then `afterpage` is used to insert your figure.

(Why does the page number need to be `3` so that the figure goes into page `5` is unclear to me).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{everypage}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\AddEverypageHook{
  \ifthenelse{\value{page}=3}{
    \afterpage{
      \begin{figure}[t]
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
          \begin{axis}
            \addplot {cos(x)};
          \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
      \end{figure}
    }
  }{}
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-40]

\end{document}
```

This might be overkill. I bet there are better ways to do this!

Comment: Better to check `\value{page}` rather than `\thepage`, as the latter might be redefined to something other than `\arabic`.

Comment: @Werner Fixed. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can just place the figure physically near the text on the page 5 and use the following to get the figure on the top of the page:

```
\begin{figure}[t]
\includegraphics{fig}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: I think the OP doesn't know where in the text, page 5 will start since that depends on how the text will flow.

Comment: @alfC When the document is in final form it's quite easy to do as suggested here.

Answer (score 0):

To force a figure on a specific place you can use the parameter 'H'(ere)

```
\begin{figure}[H]
```

Although you can not specify the page number explicitly, the suggestion increases control over the placement of the figure (which still depends on the text around it).

Comment: How does this guarantee that the figure will appear at the top of page 5? It could be anywhere, depending on the text around it.